# Python - Replace part of regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following piece of code:

```
import re
s = "Example {String}"
replaced = re.sub('{.*?}', 'a', s)
print replaced
```

Which prints:

`Example a`

Is there a way to modify the regex so that it prints:

`Example {a}`

That is I would like to replace only the .* part and keep all the surrounding characters. However, I need the surrounding characters to define my regex. Is this possible?

Comment: `re.sub('{.*?}', '{a}', s)` ? or `re.sub('({).*?(})', '\1a\2', s)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways to do this, either capture your pre- and post-fixes, or use lookbehinds and lookaheads.

```
# capture
s = "Example {String}"
replaced = re.sub(r'({).*?(})', r'\1a\2', s)

# lookaround
s = "Example {String}"
replaced = re.sub(r'(?<={).*?(?=})', r'a', s)
```

If you capture you pre- and post-fixes, you're able to use those capture groups in your substitution using `\{capture_num}`, e.g. `\1` and `\2`.

If you use lookarounds, you essentially DON'T MATCH those pre-/post-fixes, you simply **assert that they are there**. Thus the substitution only swaps the letters in between.

Of course for this simple sub, the better solution is probably:

```
re.sub(r'{.*?}', r'{a}', s)
```